# Configure Clearcase server for CCRC and web interface

Tags: clearcase, ibmhttpserver

I have clearcase and clearquest 7.1.2.13 installed in a server.
I want to make them accesible through  ClearCase Remote Client and through Web interface.
Also I have IBM HTTP server 6.1(which comes with CC installed in the same machine
How can I acheive this?

Please let me know if any other details are required.

Regards,
Nush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> make them accessible through ClearCase Remote Client

That means adding a CCRC server called **CMServer** which will have access to the vob server.
It was known before as the Rational Web Platform: see "[Migrating from Rational Web Platform to CM Server](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_ccrc_config_cqweb_conf_2host_websvr.htm)"
(In ClearCase8, it becomes a [CCRC WAN Server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_upgr_rwp.htm))

As mentioned in "[Deploying ClearCase 7.1 CM server on Windows server 2008 platform](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21403706)", ClearCase 7.1 CM server was developed on top of IBM WebSphere Application Server 6.1.

You can use an [existing Whepshere server to install the CM server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearquest.webadmin.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcm_server%2Fc_cmsvr_use_w_full_was.htm).

Comment: how can i connect clearquest schema repositories to the CMserver?

Comment: @user3437212 https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.webadmin.doc/topics/cm_server/c_configuring_cmserver.htm is a good starting point.